# How to write a recursive function to print a string a certain number of times?

Tags: python, recursion

I have been trying to write a python function which will receive two arguments: `x` which is the number of times to repeat and `y` which is the number or string to be repeated.

So far this is what I have been able to come up with, but I can't seem to be able to determine how to do it recursively.

```
def recurse(x, y):
    final = []
    if x == 0:
        return ("")
    else:
        x = x - 1
        final.append(recurse(x,y))              
    return final
```

If `recurse(3,"Cat")` is called, the output is meant to look like this:

```
print recurse(3, 'cat')
['cat','cat','cat']
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: To understand recursion, you need to understand recursion :) You need to call the recurse function from recurse itself.

Comment: Watching the film "Inception" also helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def recurse(x, y):
    final = []
    if times == 0:
```

You can't just reference "times" as if it's some kind of magic floaty variable available anywhere and everywhere. The first time in here, `times` will have no value. And the next time through, you're hoping you can just pick the value of `times` out of thin air and it will magically be what it was somewhere else, during some previous run.

The only variables you can work with are the ones completely inside your function - or ones which are passed in from outside, and returned out at the end.

```
def recurse(times, word):
    if times == 1:
        return [word]
    else:
        return [word] + recurse(times-1, word)

print(recurse(3, 'cat'))
```

[Try it online at repl.it](https://repl.it/Dbbl)

It takes a number of times as an input, it returns `[word]` plus ( It takes a number of times - 1 as an input, it returns `[word]` plus ( It takes a number of times - 1 as an input, it returns `[word]` ).

Note there's no accumulator list like `final = []` because each time through the function it will be empty again. The accumulation happens implicitly in the way the programming language calls functions and returns values. Python will hold `[word]` in memory itself while it calculates the next recurse() output.

Comment: Am sorry about the `times` reference. I made a mistake in my code. I have corrected my question now though.

Answer (score 1):

True functional recursion should have *no* assignments (i.e. state).
This can be achieved using what's called an *accumulator*, i.e. an array that is built up successively and passed to each recursive step, until the base case occurs, causing the accumulator's final form to be returned directely, and indirectly *all the way back* to the initial calling instance.

```
>>> def recurse(Iters, text, Accumulator=[]):
...   if Iters == 0: return Accumulator                   # base case
...   return recurse(Iters-1, text, Accumulator + [text]) # recursive step
... 
>>> recurse(3, 'helle')
['helle', 'helle', 'helle']
```

Note that there is no change of *state* at any point; all "updates" occur at the point of calling the next recursive step with updated arguments.